# how to install nodejs8.x on centos7? i got error

Tags: node.js, centos7

I have to install nodejs8 on centos 7.
However , the installation failed.
I'm attaching the code I excuted and the execution result below, so please help me

<> ===================================================

[root@localhost ~]# sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -

[root@localhost ~]# sudo yum install gcc-c++ make

[root@localhost ~]# sudo yum install -y nodejs

Total download size: 32 M
Installed size: 92 M
Downloading packages:
No Presto metadata available for nodesource
nodejs-14.18.3-1nodesource.x86 FAILED
https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-14.18.3-1nodesource.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- `ETA
Trying other mirror.
Error downloading packages:
2:nodejs-14.18.3-1nodesource.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
===================================================+++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Tangential to the core of your question, but why are you trying to install a version of Node that was completely EOL'd in 2019? There are likely severe security risks in running such an ancient version of Node.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to try:

> **NOTE** - Tested on CentOS 7.9.

1. Use the setup program (this is what you did, but it doesn't look like you installed the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL)):

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum install gcc-c++ make
sudo yum install nodejs
```

2. If that does not work, download the tarball and install manually:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/node-v8.17.0-linux-x64.tar.gz -P ~/Downloads
cd ~/Downloads
sudo tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node*.tar.gz
```

Afterwards, check that nodejs was installed:

```
$ node -v
v8.17.0

$ npm -v
6.13.4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Install Manual is works very well!!

Comment: YW @sys090407, but please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work